# How can I tell the Closure Compiler not to rename an inner function using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

How can I tell the Closure Compiler not to rename an inner function? E.g., given this code:

```
function aMeaninglessName() {
    function someMeaningfulName() {
    }

    return someMeaningfulName;
}
```

...I'm fine with Closure renaming the outer function (I actively want it to, to save space), but I want the function name `someMeaningfulName` left alone (so that the name shown in call stacks for it is "someMeaningfulName", not "a" or whatever). This despite the fact that the code calling it will be doing so via the reference returned by the factory function, not by the name in the code. E.g., this is purely for debugging support.

Note that I want the function to have ***that actual name***, not be anonymous and assigned to some property using that name, so for instance this is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065918/how-i-can-mark-function-as-private-to-renaming-it-by-google-closure-compiler).

This somewhat obscure use case doesn't seem to be covered by either the externs or exports functionality. (I was kind of hoping there'd be some [annotation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) I could throw at it.) But I'm no Closure Compiler guru, I'm hoping some of you are. Naturally, if there's just no way to do that, that's an acceptable answer.

---

(The use case is a library that creates functions in response to calls into it. I want to provide a version of the library that's been pre-compressed by Closure with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS, but if someone is using that copy of the library with their own uncompressed code and single-stepping into the function in a debugger [or other similar operations], I want them to see the meaningful name. I could get around it with `eval`, or manually edit the compressed result [in fact, the context is sufficiently unique I could throw a `sed` script at it], but that's awkward and frankly takes us into "not worth bothering" territory, hence looking for a simple, low-maintenance way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this.  You would have to create a custom subclass of the CodingConvention class to indicate that your methods are "local" externs (support for this was added to handle the Prototype library).  It is possible that InlineVariables, InlineFunctions, or RemoveUsedVariables will still try to remove the name and would also need to be fixed up.

Another approach is to use the source maps to remap the stack traces to the original source.

Comment: So if I thought it was worth it, I'd use my own local customized version of the compiler that has a `CodingConventions.Proxy` to wrap the default coding convention, and override...what, `isPrivate` to make it return `false` for that member?

Comment: isExported(String name, boolean local) is the method of interest, specifically when "local" is true.

Comment: Thanks. So then I have to hack `CommandLineRunner` to add a flag as well? And from the look of things, I probably want to wrap or extend `ClosureCodingConvention` rather than the default, to get the same behavior I'd get normally plus my special bit. On the whole that's not too bad, Closure downloads and builds without any hassle. If I feel really ambitious, I might add an annotation instead and offer it as a patch.

Comment: I was unaware of any etiquette in this regard.  I seemly meant "don't forget to vote if you found this information helpful".

Comment: Am I right that I also have to hack `CommandLineRunner` and such?

Comment: Only if you want to make it optional.  If you are only doing it for your own use that doesn't seem necessary.  If you wanted to try to submit back to main compiler repository, I would start a conversation on the compiler's mailing list to see if it would be accepted, I doubt adding a command-line options would be (as the command-line is complex enough) but the having it part of the java API might be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. (I don't seem to have been notified of your comment, which seems odd; normally it's automatic when there are only two people in the conversation.)

Answer (score 0):

read the following section

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export

Two options basically, use object['functionName'] = obj.functionName or the better way
use exportSymbol and exportProperty both on the goog object, here is the docs link for that

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html

-- edit
ah, i see now, my first answer is not so great for you. The compiler has some interesting flags, the one which might interest you is DEBUG, which you can pass variables into the compiler which will allow you to drop some debugging annotations in via logging or just a string which does nothing since you are using simple mode.

so if you are using closure you can debug against a development version which is just a page built with dependiencies resolved. we also the drop the following in our code

```
if(DEBUG){
  logger.info('pack.age.info.prototype.func');
}
```

Comment: also there used to be a firebug plugin, but it is now defunct. if you are using closure in general, what we tend to do is build a development version which is just resolves dependencies (in chrome debugger you actually then see the whole class path instead of just Object as in Firebug) and have the following type of line in each function member